# Does site ID change for migrated site collections?

Tags: sharepoint-server, site-collection, migration

We have migrated our farm from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2010 via Database detach and attach method.

In this course does the site id of the site collections get changed after they are migrated?

If a site collection has Site id as `XXXX1234` in MOSS 2007, does it remain the same in SharePoint 2010 (`XXXX1234`) or does it get changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On first I would say NO. Only the databaseId could change - only if you request it (-AssignNewDatabaseId).

I did it once or twice and never notice a SiteId change. Did you test this on non-production environment?